# How to style checbox when with background color and border in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is the code for checkbox :

How to style checkbox with background color and border when checked.

```
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="vehicle.selected" name="selectedVariants[]" 
value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-checked="{{vehicle.selected}}" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css else you can also look into angular material design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css). But if you want to do it the angular way use ng-class and you shouldn't use interpolation on ng-checked

Answer (score 0):

No need for angular, or any JS for that matter.

html (notice that I have added a class):

```
<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="vehicle.selected" name="selectedVariants[]" class="custom-class-here" 
value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-checked="{{vehicle.selected}}" />
```

css:

```
.custom-class-here:checked {
    background-color: #123456;
    border: 1px solid #654321;
}
```